# Oracle histogram of data growth for a tablespace

Tags: sql, oracle, histogram

Is it possible to generate a histogram of the data growth for a specific tablespace within an Oracle instance?  What I mean specifically is a query like this:

```
select * from internal_growth_report
where metric_Date between start and finish
```

which would give me an output that would contain data like this:

```
Data start    Data End    percent increase     last accessed   
0kb             15kb       (infinity) 100%      Today  
12kb            12kb        0%                  3 weeks ago   
20kb            10kb        -50%                Today
```

Comment: You may be interested in [DBMS_SPACE.OBJECT_GROWTH_TREND](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_space.htm#i1002179).  It doesn't appear to work for tablespaces, but there's probably a way to use it to get that information.  But I don't have any practical experience with that advisor functionality.  You may want to try asking this question on DBA.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt something like this exists. I use this query to find what is taking up space in a schema, if it helps you.

```
select segment_name object
,      round(sum(bytes)/1024/1024) size_mb
from   user_extents
group by segment_name
order by 2 desc
```